# Setting SQL datetime to minimum using C# DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a datetime column in SQL Server.  I believe the minimum it can be is some date in 1753 or something.  My Entity Framework POCO representing the table contains a DateTime.  I'd like to set the datetime in the database to the minimum it can be set to.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of doing this, if I may ask? Wouldn't a nullable datetime field be an easier sollution?

Comment: Not really sure if I understood you, but can't you do: `DateTime sqlMinDateTime = new DateTime(1753, 01, 01);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That value can be retrieved using the following property;

```
SqlDateTime.MinValue
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx for more details.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. `SqlDateTime` has an implicit conversion to `DateTime`, I believe, so this should work just fine.

Comment: You need to use System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value, which is a DateTime.